# Service with post on creation

Tags: angularjs, http-post, qunit

I have a service that does a post on creation, something like the following:

```
angular.module('app', ['$strap.directives'])
.service('dataService', function ($rootScope, $http, $location) {

    this.postInitCommands = function (path, command) {

        $http.post(path,
                   command,
                   {headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.dir(data);
            });
    };

    this.postInitCommands("/example/path", {example: 'command'});
}
```

However, when I go to test some of my controllers that use this module and service, they all failed immediately with error `Unexpected request: POST /example/path`.

If I take out the call to `postInitCommands()` in the service creation, this error goes away and I can test my controllers.

My qunit setup is as follows:

```
var fittingDataServiceMock, injector, ctrl, $scope, $httpBackend;

module("Fitting Controller Test", {
    setup: function() {
        injector = angular.injector(['ngMock', 'ng','app']);
        $scope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        dataServiceMock= injector.get('dataService');
        $httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/example/test').respond(200, {});
        ctrl = injector.get('$controller')(DoubleVariableController, { $scope: $scope, dataService: dataServiceMock});
    },
    teardown: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the expected request to after the service instantiation?

Comment: no I didn't seemed to solve some issues but not all.. now I am getting a different error that is probably a different thing entirley. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service instance is constructed when you call `injector.get('dataService')`. The POST is made when that happens, so you need to tell your test to expect a HTTP request before that line.

```
var fittingDataServiceMock, injector, ctrl, $scope, $httpBackend;

module("Fitting Controller Test", {
    setup: function() {
        injector = angular.injector(['ngMock', 'ng','app']);
        $scope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

        $httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/example/test').respond(200, {});

        dataServiceMock= injector.get('dataService');
        ctrl = injector.get('$controller')(DoubleVariableController, { $scope: $scope, dataService: dataServiceMock});
    },
    teardown: function() {

    }
});
```